# Redirect user from mobile application to mobile web browser for donate

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I'm currently working on a mobile application in which we make donations.
Apple guidelines does not allow payment directly in application for donations.
I would like to redirect my users from my mobile application to their web browser on their devices.
How can i authenticate the user without force him to enter his credentials ?

What i've done so far is that i created a "ActionToken" in my database. When the user click on pay on the mobile application, a call to the database is done to generate a token (a simple GUID), and save it in database.
After that, the application redirect to the web page who read the token and retreive the associated user.

What i would like is to eliminate the generation of the token before redirecting to the browser.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

When using the authentication in Azure App Service, a JSON web token (JWT) would be presented in the `x-zumo-auth` request header when the mobile client interacts with the azure mobile app. More details you could refer to [Authentication and authorization in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview).

Per my understanding, you could leverage the `authenticationToken` generated by your mobile app backend and pass it as the query string with your payment url, then you could send ajax request against your mobile app endpoint (e.g. custom Web API,etc.) with the `x-zumo-auth` header. For the payment Web API in your mobile app backend, you could refer to adrian hall's book [Custom HTTP Endpoints](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter4/custom/) and [How to: Retrieve authenticated user information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#user-info).

For retrieving the value for `x-zumo-auth` header, you could access `MobileServiceClient.CurrentUser.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken` after you invoked `MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync` in your mobile client. More details about adding authentication to the iOS app, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#add-authentication-to-the-ios-app).